# How to edit :After-Content() when hovering?

Tags: css

I want to add a style to "after"-content, when hovering the actual element. Like so:

```
    span.link_wer:after{
        content:'zu uns';
        vertical-align:1.8em;
    }

    span.link_wer:hover>span.link_wer:after{
        vertical-align:4.8em;

}
```

But that doesn't do anything. Is that due to the wrong operator or because that's not possible with :after-content?

Comment: Without seeing the html structure it is impossible to give an answer.

Comment: You can simply concatenate the selectors, i.e.: `span.link_wer:hover:after`

Comment: make a working snippet.